# How to make the .map function to work consuming an API

Tags: reactjs

I'm consuming an API and I'm not getting through the map and show the data.
I'm using React Redux with hooks.

this is how my Home looks like:

```
const Home = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { profiles } = useSelector(state => ({
    profiles: state.ProfileReducer.profiles
  }));

  console.log("Do we have it???? ", profiles);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(ProfileMiddleware.getOneProfile(USERNAME));
  }, [dispatch]);

  console.log("Profiles Data", profiles);

  return (
    <>
      {profiles.data &&
        profiles.data.map((p, k) => <h1>${p.profiles.firstname}</h1>)} // This not work
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

The API response I can see in my Redux until the last `console.log("Profiles Data", profiles);`
The API looks like this:

```
{
imageUrl: "http://localhost:5000/images/file-1580082526473.png"
_id: "5e2c98fc3d785252ce5b5693"
firstname: "Jakos"
surname: "Lemi"
email: "lemi@email.com"
bio: "My bio bio"
title: "Senior IT developer"
area: "Copenhagen"
username: "Jakos"
experience: (2) [{…}, {…}]
createdAt: "2020-01-25T19:37:32.727Z"
updatedAt: "2020-01-28T16:22:36.650Z"
}
```

Honestly cannot understand how should that map work as I'm new using Redux and FUnctional components and I got lost.

What I'm trying to do is to show one USERNAME data in the home which is like a profile user and I want to display to display that data somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profiles is an object, you don't have to map/loop anywhere, just:

```
return (
    <div>
       {profiles.data && profiles.data.firstname}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: This giving an error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should work. You are using map on an object, it is only for arrays

```
const {data} = [profiles];

{data &&
data.map((p, k) => <h1>${p.profiles.firstname}</h1>)}
```

```js
let apiData = {
imageUrl: "http://localhost:5000/images/file-1580082526473.png",
_id: "5e2c98fc3d785252ce5b5693",
firstname: "Jakos",
surname: "Lemi",
email: "lemi@email.com",
bio: "My bio bio",
title: "Senior IT developer",
area: "Copenhagen",
username: "Jakos",
createdAt: "2020-01-25T19:37:32.727Z",
updatedAt: "2020-01-28T16:22:36.650Z",
}



const result = [apiData].map(res => res.firstname);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: No change this is my repo if you want to give a look I have no idea what's wrong
https://github.com/Jakub41/LinkedIn-Redux

Comment: I have updated the answer with snippet see if that helps